# Creating unique ids and assigned them in html for use Javascript

Tags: javascript

i am currently trying to create unique ids in html. 
However, i am not sure if this below codes is creating unqiue ids and being assigned to the element itself in the html or just creating unqiue ids only. 
Please help me out. If this is not assigned them in html, how am i supposed to do them?

```
var abcElements = document.querySelectorAll('.like');

    for (var i = 0; i < abcElements.length; i++){

    abcElements[i].id = 'like_' + i;
    alert(abcElements[i].id);
}
```

Updates:
I have include all the related codes in

```
<td><a onclick="return confirm(this)"><input class="switch" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="like" data-off="unlike" data-onstyle="danger" data-width="90" data-height="30" type="checkbox"></a></td>

    <td style="display:none;"><div class="like">${like}</div></td>
```

Javascript

```
var abcElements = document.querySelectorAll('.switch');
                     var status = document.querySelectorAll('.like');
                     alert(status.length);
                       for (var i = 0; i < abcElements.length; i++) 
                       {

                            abcElements[i].id = 'switch_' + i;
                            alert(abcElements[i].id);

                            for (var j = 0; j < status.length; j++) 
                            {
                                status[j].id = 'like_' + j;

                                var statusText = $('#'+status[j].id+'').html();
                                alert(statusText);
                                if(statusText == 'true' )
                                { 
                              $('#'+abcElements[i].id+'').bootstrapToggle('on'); 
                                } 


                            }

                        }
```

Comment: Where's the problem? `abcElements[i].id` **does** set the element's `ID` property...

Comment: This should work just fine.

Comment: i am trying to get 'like' div html. The div is populated in data table so i assigned them an individual unique ids so i can retrieve them out based on their unique ids. However i get all of the html instead of just that one that i wanted.

Comment: How are you trying to get the divs ? Can you post that code ?

Comment: updated @RajeshP

Comment: Add the generated html. Where is the switch class div?

Comment: done updated @H77

Comment: @lel this example has only one element with switch class and one with like. It is not good enough to help solve your problem

Comment: er but that is all my codes. I have nothing else to show @H77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized i am assigning the ids for individual divs. I just need to move one of the loops outside that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I assume this is what you want?

```js
$("table tr").each(function(row) {
  var $row = $(this);
  var statusText = $row.find(".like").html();
  console.log("status: " + statusText);
  if (statusText == "true") {
    // $row.find("input.switch").bootstrapToggle('on');
    $row.find("input.switch").prop("checked", ($row.find(".like").html() === "true"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span><input class="switch" type="checkbox">switch 1</span>
    </td>
    <td style="display:none;">
      <div class="like">false</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span><input class="switch" type="checkbox">switch 2</span>
    </td>
    <td style="display:none;">
      <div class="like">true</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i am trying to get 'like' div html. The div html is populated in data table so i assigned them an individual unique ids so i can retrieve them out based on their unique ids. However i get all of the html instead of just that one that i wanted.

Comment: @lel see the updated example. It gets the proper html based on the id. I think we will need more code to identify what the problem is.

Comment: @lel check if this what you want.

Comment: i found out that i was supposed to take out the for loop that is inside and place it outside. Thanks for your help anyways!